# What do we call these 'squeezed' papers?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In my mother tongue, there is a word for it, and it is a noun.

The action is observed when you think the paper is waste. You ***squeeze*** it, and it *loses* its texture/avatar. Then, it is no more straight or flat.

Here is the image. Check those papers. What have they become?

[image: waste paper in a dustbin]

Precisely...

> I wanted to put everything in words. I tried it on a paper. I did not like it. I __________ it and threw it in a dustbin.
>
> You find nothing in this dustbin except some __________ papers

Comment: A possible alternative with *wad*: *I wad the paper up; a wad of paper; wadded balls of paper*

Comment: BTW, you are using the word **avatar** incorrectly.

Comment: TRomano it's in my mother tongue and also in sanskrit from where it's derived. So here, nativeness may not work. And I confirm this. :-)

Comment: @TRomano Yeah but now I want to start using the word "avatar" in strange ways. I'm sure when I do, people will get funny looks on their avatars. Maybe when I go to the dry cleaners I'll ask them if they can give my shirts back their avatar. It's just a cool word.

Comment: exactly @ToddWilcox. So, this means 'avatar' has many other meanings those are **not** yet known to native speakers or at least are 'strange' to them.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that 'avatar' is being confused with 'shape' since both can refer to the 'physical form' of something. The difference is that 'avatar' typically means the physical incarnation of a deity in hinduism, whereas a 'shape' is the physical form of a real world object.

Comment: @DamkerngT. to "wad" is to pack tightly.

Comment: @Ben It's British English vs. American English, perhaps?

Comment: Bing image search for "Crumpled paper", "screwed-up paper", "wadded paper" and "scrunched up paper" all produce similar images.

Comment: Those are [origami rocks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7OekeuNTq9A). ;)

Comment: @MaulikV no. If you're speaking english, you're speaking english. "avatar" only has a few meanings in english. it doesn't mean whatever you're using it to mean, period. the entire point of language is to be understood. native speakers are the ones who know the language best. your job is to learn to speak like they do.

Comment: @sgroves *job!* :) When linguists derive any word from any other language, they *retain* the meaning. It's *irony* that James Cameron used it first for its 'one' meaning and the *natives* have been following it ever since! Since native speakers seem to be interested in its meaning, let me tell you. The one that *loses* its original shape, traditional looks, size, or becomes **entirely** different is called 'avatar changed'. Now, it's your take -learn it or trash it. I won't call this 'job' for you at all!

Comment: @MaulikV Are you sure that that use of *avatar* (avatar changed) is in Sanskrit? Could it be that it's in some other language that borrowed or derived the word from Sanskrit? -- I'm not saying that I know Sanskrit, though. I'm just curious about it.

Comment: *Avatar* is basically an ***incarnation*** or say -a birth of Indian gods and goddesses **on the earth for a particular mission/reason**. But since Hindus *do* identify 'faces' of their gods, the almighty **change** their *avatar* i.e. size, shape, face (and even their *form of their appearance i.e. human-like figure') etc. to **remain unidentified**. Thus, the word extends its meaning. And now, even in many local languages, this word is used when something is **changed** from its original form. It's a long discussion short though! even @DamkerngT. can change avatar in that sense! cont...

Comment: cont... [Here is the original use of 'avatar'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashavatara) wherein the Lord Vishnu took 10 different avatars for the purpose to restore cosmic order. Note that the god had taken an avatar of fish, tortoise, half man-half lion, dwarf...and many more.

Comment: So, is "avatar changed" for paper in Hindi or in Sanskrit or both? -- BTW, I know that sense of the word, 'cause the full name of the city I live in has the word "avatar" in it.

Comment: Stick to 'avatar'. Because to make others understand, I added 'changed'. Avatar is Sanskrit but its meaning 'to change from its primary appearance' is in *Sanskrit, Guajrati, Marathi*..and could be a few more languages. @DamkerngT. It was a metaphor - non-living things don't have avatar! that's the reason, I said loses its original shape, size, texture, form i.e. avatar

Comment: Interesting - [Vamana (dwarf) avatar of Vishnu](http://www.ruchiskitchen.com/fifth-vamana-avatar-the-dwarf-incarnation/) in which he **completely changed his form** and became a dwarf and then grew the size of the sky!

Comment: Interesting. This use of avatar to mean the dorm or the shape of anything in Sanskrit is new to me. The sense that I'm familiar with roughly means "to incarnate" or "to die" as in a supreme being leaving their current state in order to descend to our earth. I still doubt if it's really felicitous in Sanskrit. Perhaps I may post it as a question when we have a Sanskrit stack. (Too bad that its proposal didn't survive!)

Comment: Ah, a modern day example - we have 'gravatar' graphic avatar where you can ***change*** yourself into a cartoonish character! Hundreds of applications available to **change your avatar**! That is, appearance. @DamkerngT. Aw..this is getting long and probably we are digressing. We'll talk sometime on this.

Comment: The Vamana avatar is used in the more common sense of the word, I think, that is "an incarnated being", as a noun.

Comment: Got it! Sorry for talking about this too long. It's just that I'm interested in Sanskrit, too.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

***Crumple*** is a good option.

> I wanted to put everything in words. I tried it on a paper. I did not like it. I **crumpled** it and threw it in a dustbin.
>
> You find nothing in this dustbin except some **crumpled** papers.

Comment: I'm 30 seconds late. +1

Comment: Do people really use other words (besides crumple) for this?

Comment: @TRomano attempt using square brackets around the words, and parentheses around the URL: [square brackets and parentheses](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crumpled+balls+of+*&year_start=180‌​0&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ccrumpled%20balls%‌​20of%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcrumpled%20balls%20of%20paper%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcrumpl‌​ed%20balls%20of%20newspaper%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: your link doesn't work properly. It shows no graphic results.  I think the asterisk in the url is giving SE problems.

Comment: In the UK it's more usual to say "I crumpled it up"... here "up" acts informally as an intensifier.. Something which is "crumpled up" is more crumpled than something which is merely "crumpled".

Comment: @yakk yes, obviously; see the other answers. i don't find it hard to believe that people in different regions of the world might use different words for the same concept.

Comment: I think the 'up' in the phrase 'crumpled up' means 'to completion' -- i.e. these papers are completely crumpled, and cannot be crumpled any further. For another example, 'fill up' -- the container is completely full, cannot be filled any more, and no additional material can be added.

Answer (score 15):

Another is "wadded up"

> I wadded up the paper into a ball and threw it in the garbage.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wadded

> verb (used with object), wadded, wadding.
>
> 7. to form (material) into a wad.
>
> 8.
>   **to roll tightly (often followed by up):
>   He wadded up his cap and stuck it into his pocket.**
>
> 9.
>   to hold in place by a wad:
>   They rammed and wadded the shot into their muskets.
>
> 10.
>   to put a wad into; stuff with a wad.

Comment: As a native American English speaker, 'wadded up' sounds the best and most-specific to me.

Comment: To "wad" means to pack tightly. Doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Ben It also has sense (7) above, “to form into a wad”. Since *wad* (noun) itself doesn't denote “tightly-packed,” *wadded* would appear to apply just fine.

Comment: @Ben this appears to be a uk/american difference that you're unaware of. "wad" is extremely common for this use in am.e—every native am.e speaker would understand this meaning immediately. it's probably *more* common than "crumple" in am.e, although am.e does use "crumple" as well.

Comment: +1 for regional difference: I'm in Canada, and "wadded up" sounds unfamiliar to me; "crumpled" or even "scrunched up" are common here.

Comment: To me, wadding (or balling) up a piece of paper is slightly different from scrunching/crumpling/screwing it up, in that wadding it up implies more determination and force, turning the paper into a _compact_ ball. The other verbs can just be making a light, semi-ballish structure out of it, which wadding isn’t in my head. For instance, [this](http://tinyurl.com/nlvsyr2) is scrunched/screwed/crumpled (up), while [this](http://tinyurl.com/pgu53e8) is wadded or balled up.

Comment: Wadding up sounds very wierd to my native  English ears! I'd be wondering 'to make, or pad what, out of it?' In UK English we'd say 'I screwed it up and threw it away'. This carries No connotation of 'error' as it might in American English.

Answer (score 12):

"Balled up" is a good option. It visually explains what is done to the paper.

> I wanted to put everything in words. I tried it on a paper. I did not like it. I balled it up and threw it in a dustbin.
>
> You find nothing in this dustbin except some balled up papers.

Comment: What location is this common in? I have certainly never heard this used in British English.

Comment: I've heard it used in American English. Along with "Scrunched up" and "wadded up".

Answer (score 10):

"**Scrunched up papers**" is exactly what you're looking for.

> I wanted to put everything in words. I tried it on a paper. I did not like it. I ***scrunched it up*** and threw it in a dustbin.
>
> You find nothing in this dustbin except some ***scrunched up*** papers

Comment: Spot on. Though I'd wait for some more answers to flow in.

Comment: I've been wondering for a while. How do you make that paragraph yellow and make it have an indent?

Comment: Use a *right* angular bracket [>] for that.

Comment: This works, but note that it's very informal sounding. "Scrunch" is a "cute" word, and especially in this sense. (Normally, it means a _person_ making themselves small, or tightening their face or hands, so this is anthropomorphic.)

Comment: This might be spot on in some places, but I've never heard it in my life in the USA. Maybe it's British? "Crumpled" is what I hear all the time.

Comment: I would use "scrunched up" happily in conversation (for example, when describing what comes out of the printer after a paper jam) but for some reason it's one of those words I would be reluctant to use in writing.

Comment: @mattdm It puts me in mind of the word "scrunchies".

Comment: It's used in Britain.  Here's a quote from Red Dwarf: "You can always tell when he's tense. The way he scrunches up cups and throws them in the bin. And I'm not talking about styrofoam here, I'm talking enamel."  I would also use crumpled or screwed up as the other answers suggest though.

Comment: -1:  In American English (Internet English), scrunching is infrequently done to anything other than faces.  Trying to scrunch anything else is likely to confuse people.  "You made a face from a can and then did something with it?" or "You made a can from a face and then crushed it?"  No.  Avoid the ambiguity.  Papers aren't scrunched.

Comment: Why downvote an answer that's correct? An answer might be correct in one type of a language, but not in another. That doesn't mean it deserves a downvote.

Comment: I think you should change the word from 'scrunch' to 'crunch'. It seems that as I read [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/scrunch_1) and [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scrunch),

Comment: As an American, I agree with @MichaelKay -- "scrunched" is a great word for paper that's jammed in a printer (or copier); as such, it seems more applicable to paper that's been wrinkled up in a very linear fashion, e.g. https://cartouchescertifiees.com/blogue/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bourrage-papier.jpg

Comment: @killermist American English is **not** the same as Internet English. English on the Internet takes all kinds of different shapes and forms—and besides, scrunching up paper is perfectly valid in American English, too; see, for example, [Merriam-Webster’s definition 2b](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrunch). Papers are scrunched up all the time, even if not necessarily where you live.

Answer (score 9):

**Screwed-up** is an alternative to scrunched up.

> I wanted to put everything in words. I tried it on a paper. I did not like it. I **screwed it up** and threw it in a dustbin.
>
> You'll find nothing in this dustbin except some **screwed-up** papers.

As found in the [Collins English dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/screw-up):

> ***Verb*** If you screw something such as a piece of paper into a ball, you squeeze it or twist it tightly so that it is in the shape of a ball. BRIT.
>
> "He screwed the paper into a ball and tossed it into the fire."
>
> AM *use crush*

Comment: not quite. It's common in British English. I'll add a link

Comment: Thank you! It is best to provide details when sharing an answer to avoid misconception and ambiguity. (+1)

Comment: In American English, this does not mean crumpled into a ball; it means "ruined by mistakes". My first assumption would be that the paper contained a form, and you filled it out wrong.

Comment: In my experience (British English) this option would be far more commonly used than any of the other options presented.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely not American English. Screwed up is used in a VERY different way in AmE. I can't stress enough that this would get very confused looks and problems with understanding in America.

Comment: @Zessa... In all fairness, it hasn't been specified whether it's AmE or British English.

Comment: @Ilessa Yes of course. Thus my warning. I just didn't want the learner to miss that it was as British thing and possibly use it with American colleagues.

Comment: I use 'screwed up' quite often and it is *entirely* different

Comment: Screwed up has multiple meanings. One meaning is to make a mistake (which I'd like to point out is a colloquialism), another is (according to wiktionary) "(transitive) To twist into a contorted state", which is the meaning applied here.

Comment: -1:  screwed up implies user error, not preparation to be discarded.

Comment: @killermist Incorrect. _Screwed-up_ implied user error if that makes sense in the context given; in other cases, it does not. “He screwed up the scrap of paper and chucked it in the bin” does not in any way whatsoever imply that he erred with the scrap of paper—not even in AmE, even if it is less common there.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "He screwed up the scrap of paper and chucked it in the bin" in AmE (and I KNOW this) means "He screwed up (errored) on filling out the [red tape] paper, threw it away, and started again."  I'm sorry if your perception of American English is that out of whack.

Comment: @killermist You seem to be labo(u)ring under the misapprehension that there is no regional variation within AmE. I can assure you there is. I have heard Americans, from varying parts of the country, talking about screwing up paper into a ball with absolutely no hint of any kind of user error on quite a few occasions. It may not be common where you are (I agree it’s less common than the other answers overall in AmE), but there is nothing incorrect or downvote-worthy about it. “I’ve never heard this” is not a reason to downvote an answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet To be clear, if a person were to use it in verbal conversation in Indianapolis, Indiana, I would take pause and ask for clarification what the person was trying to say.  This is opposed to any person saying verbally that they scrunched, balled, or crumpled up the paper and [pick a form] discarded it.  "Screwed up" == error.  Used out of context == ambiguity.

Comment: In English English (I'm a native speaker) we would normally say 'I screwed up the paper and threw it away'. 'I screwed it up and threw it away'. Meaning I squeezed it into a ball and put it in the bin. There is no sense of 'error' at all, in that, in English. Crumpled and wadded would be more poetic words to use - not everday speech. In the UK people generally also know the expression 'I screwed up' to mean a mistake has been made. This is distinct from paper-balling however! Screwed up is a separate phrase, known as an Americanism, and also used to mean 'I made a mistake' in other contexts.